# Check whether a Kerberos KeyTab file is valid in Java

Tags: java, kerberos, gssapi, keytab

I'm working on a Java code base that checks whether a Kerberos KeyTab file is valid, but it uses the internal class `sun.security.krb5.internal.ktab.KeyTab` for its `isValid()` method. Currently, it is doing the following:

```
File keytabFile = new File("/path/to/keytab");
KeyTab keytab = KeyTab.getInstance(keytabFile);
boolean keytabIsValid = keytab.isValid();
if (!keytabIsValid) {
   throw new ApplicationSpecificException("Keytab is not valid");
}
```

Accessing this method is more of an annoyance in Java 9, so I'm looking for a way to avoid using this internal class, but browsing through the JDK source, I haven't seen anything that exposes the `isValid()` method or an equivalent in a non-internal class.

Are there options which don't rely on hacks like reflecting on private methods or accessing internal APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)**

You can try using the native executable to validate the keytab file and proceed as per the output to determine validity, through java [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). e.g. for linux/*nix, you can run

```
klist -k –t your.keytab
```

**2)**

Since, you already mention desire to exclude accessing internal API's, I assume you are aware of the options. But just including here for information for this particular case:

```
javac --add-exports java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.ktab=ALL-UNNAMED your-class.java
java --add-exports java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.ktab=ALL-UNNAMED your-class
```

**3)**

You can also roll out your own validator. I think the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/security/krb5/internal/ktab/KeyTab.java) is not that complex.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already doing option 2 (since I have to). It looks like option 3 might be the least bad out of these choices. I was hoping that there was some clever little class somewhere that would do what I needed, but alas.